# computer freezes when logging in after updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, login

I am running ubuntu 12.04 and yesterday i installed a few updates. i cant recall which. Afterwards i shut down the pc.

Today when booting up, i can see strange artifact behaviour in the login screen. a few black blocks appeared. and as i type my password i can see some white jibber appearing in the black blocks.

when providing my password and logging in, the computer freezes (black screen), monitors go into sleep mode and all i can do is force off the pc.

However **i am able to log in** succesfully as guest !!
How can i troubleshoot my pc, i noticed i can not sudo from the quest account.

Comment: check out this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :

Pressings crtl+alt F2 i switched to console
then i removed openarena

```
sudo apt-get remove openarena-server
```

Reboot and the problem was solved. I tried this when i noticed openarena server was started during boot.